# Binding a AutoComplete type Textbox with selected dropdown lists options in MVC Razor View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hi I have to make an auto-complete type textbox which on typing any letter searches the database and displays similarly typed combinations.

I was able to make it using jQuery, but now I want to bind the results in the textbox based on the previously selected values from two drop down lists.
I have a dropdownlist **State** and another is **City**. Both dropdown lists are cascading. Now the AutoComplete type Textbox should only display results based on the selected **StateId** and **CityId**.

View

```
 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
    <label>State<span class="error">*</span></label>
    @Html.DropDownList("StateId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["StateList"], "--Select--", new { @placeholder = "--Select--", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
    <label>City <span class="error">*</span></label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CityId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["CityList"], "--Select--", new { @placeholder = "--Select--", @class = "form-control" })

</div>

<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
    <label>Customer Name <span class="error">*</span></label>

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerName, new { @placeholder = "Enter Customer Name", @class = "required form-control", @maxlength = 100 })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName, null, new { @style = "color:red;!important" })
</div>

<input type="hidden" id="hfCustomer" name="CustomerId" />
<br /><br />
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#CustomerName").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/AutoComplete/',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {                                
                            return item;
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (e, i) {
                $("#hfCustomer").val(i.item.val);                  
            },
            minLength: 1
        });

    });

</script>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AutoComplete(string prefix)
{

    var customers = (from customer in dbContaxt.Cities
                     where customer.Name.StartsWith(prefix)
                     select new
                     {
                         label = customer.Name,
                         val = customer.CityId
                     }).ToList();

    return Json(customers);
}
```

How can I bind both selected StateId and CityId and retrieve CustomerName in the textbox? Please suggest changes in jQuery and controller.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/Home/AutoComplete/',
   data: {   data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}", stateId: "slected State Id",cityid:"Selected City ID" },
```

Controller like below

```
public JsonResult AutoComplete(string prefix,int stateId,int cityid)   
{
    var customers = (from customer in dbContaxt.Cities
    where customer.Name.StartsWith(prefix)&&customer.state==state && customer.city==city 
                     select new
                     {
                         label = customer.Name,
                         val = customer.CityId
                     }).ToList();

    return Json(customers);
}
```

Comment: Please try this.I hope you need to get customer name in auto text box based on the dropdown select

Comment: you can use the edit button, to modify - e.g. to include your comment into - your answer

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is, read the selected option value of State and City dropdown and send that in the request payload.

Also if you are specifying `contentType` as `application/json`, you should JSON stringify the payload. If your payload is a lean flat js object, you do not need to do that. Simply remove the contentType property.

dataType is a property which tells the `$.ajax` method the type of data it is expecting from the server. But if not provided, jQuery will intelligently guess it based on the response headers (`Content-Type` header) and use that. In this case, since we are explicitly returning Json from the controller, there will be response header for `Content-Type` whic hhas value `application/json`. So you can remove that as well from your call.

```
$(function() {

    $("#CustomerName").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var d = { term: request.term, 
                      stateId: $("#StateId").val(), 
                      cityId: $("#City").val() };
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("AutoComplete")',
                data: d,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return item;
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("#hfCustomer").val(i.item.val);
        },
        minLength: 1
    });

});
```

Now add these 2 parameters to your action method and you can use that to filter your data

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AutoComplete(string term,int countryId,int stateId)
{
   // to do use the parameters and filter data and return some JSON
}
```